# Is it possible to combine Bootstrap, Foundation and jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I like elements of Twitter Bootstrap, navigation system of Foundation and rich extension system of jQuery UI. Before going deep I'd like to know is it possible to combine them without some conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  I'm using them together in my projects :-)

Comment: Did you get any kind of problem with JS?

Comment: No I didn't get js problems